# Customize Bookkeeping Transactions Report: Print custom field option value instead of name/label

Tags: custom-fields, civireport, custom-reports

I am using custom fields to store additional (cost accounting) data for contributions. Using the bookkeeping transactions report, I am able to export the data.

However, when we are trying to import the data into the legacy accounting system, it does not accept the option's long name for import, but only the key value, which is stored in the custom field option value.

How can I customize the bookkeeping transactions report, in order to make it print the custom field option value instead of name/label?

Any hint is highly appreciated!

Cheers, Detlev

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're not asking how to customize reports in general, but what customization you can make to get your desired results.

You can use the `alterDisplay()` function to modify the output of your report.  Check out `CRM_Core_PseudoConstact` and its methods (`getKey`, `getLabel`, `getName`) one of those is likely to do it for you.